# How to export multiple Type Aliases?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, casting

For better capsulation I want to create a new type that includes multiple other types. `entityService` should be typed as `OakService` or `MapleService` which should be included inside `TreeService`.

One possible solition you can see inside the comments. If I uncomment the imports inside **garden.component.ts** and replace `TreeService` with `OakService | MapleService`, it will work, but I want some kind of parent type, that includes them all.

**tree.service.ts**

```
import { OakService } from './oak.service';
import { MapleService } from './maple.service';

export type TreeService = typeof OakService | MapleService;
```

**oak.service.ts**

```
import { BaseService } from './base.service';

@Injectable()
export class OakService extends BaseService {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

**maple.service.ts**

```
import { BaseService } from './base.service';

@Injectable()
export class MapleService extends BaseService {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

**garden.component.ts**

```
// import { OakService } from './oak.service';
// import { MapleService } from './maple.service';
import { TreeService } from './parent.service';

@Component()
export class GardenComponent {
  constructor(
    protected entityService: TreeService // OakService | MapleService
  ) {}
}
```

**balcony.component.ts**

```
import { MapleService } from './maple.service';

export class BalconyComponent extends GardenComponent {   
  constructor(
    protected mapleService: MapleService
  ) {
    super(mapleService);   
  }
}
```

> **Info:** The code above does not work. Your have to use the code inside the comments. The error I've got is not inside **balcony.component.ts**:
>   *ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for BaseListComponent in .../garden.component.ts: (?).*

Comment: It's primarily Angular question. Types don't exist at runtime and cannot be injected. Btw, what `entityService: TreeService` is supposed to do? Should Angular injector flip a coin and inject either OakService or MapleService?

Comment: @estus If you look inside *balcony.component.ts*, you will see, that a `MapleService` is injected. So `entityService` will be able to handle a `MapleService` and `OakService`. For example both services do have similiar functions, that are inherited from the same base service.

Comment: I see. The code you've provided isn't full. It doesn't have `@Component` decorator, while it's obviously there . Please, provide all relevant code. I assume that you specified `@Component` on GardenComponent, while it's abstract class and not workable component.

Comment: @estus I've added the decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter types in injectable class allow to skip Angular `@Inject` decorator in TypeScript and annotate a constructor for dependency injection. Types don't exist at runtime and cannot be injected.

`GardenComponent` cannot be workable component because of that. Since is used as abstract class, it shouldn't have `@Component` decorator:

```
export abstract class GardenComponent {
  constructor(
    protected entityService: TreeService // OakService | MapleService
  ) {}
}
```

While child classes should have `@Component`:

```
@Component(...)
export class BalconyComponent extends GardenComponent {   
  constructor(mapleService: MapleService) {
    super(mapleService);
  }
}
```

Constructors are mandatory in child classes because parent class doesn't contain proper annotation, and their parameters shouldn't have visibility modifiers because `this.entityService` is already assigned by parent constructor.

Comment: You've provided the right solution. Great! But I do not understand your first sentence. You mean, I could inject any component, class, service or what ever inside the abstract class, without having to add an equivalent inside `super()` of child class constructor?

Comment: The code above works because `mapleService` conforms to `TreeService` type. You would have TS error if wrong argument was provided to `super`.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292314/dependency-injection-in-abstract-class-with-typescript-and-angular-5 I've formulated the complete question here.