# Dependency injection in abstract class with TypeScript and Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, dependency-injection

I've got the `BaseComponent` which got some dependencies injected. The first dependency `EntityService` is correct and necessary.

But`AnyOtherService` is only used inside the abstract `BaseComponent`. Instead of injecting it inside the `ChildComponent`, where it is not used, I'd like to inject it only inside `BaseComonent`.

*Why do I have to push it through the `ChildComponent` towards the `BaseComponent`? The best solution would be to encapsulate it inside the `BaseComponent`.*

**base.component.ts**

```
export abstract class BaseComponent {
  constructor(
    protected entityService: EntityService,
    // protected anyOtherService: AnyOtherService // @todo add this
  ) {
  }
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component()
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent {

  constructor(
    private firstService: FirstService,
    private secondService: SecondService,
    protected anyOtherService: AnyOtherService // @todo remove this
  ) {
    super(
      firstService,
      anyOtherService // @todo remove this
    ); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can pass **Injector** to base component constructor(**UPDATE**):

```
export abstract class BaseComponent {
  protected anyOtherService: AnyOtherService;

  constructor(
    inject: Injector
    protected entityService: EntityService,
    // protected anyOtherService: AnyOtherService // @todo add this
  ) { 
     this.anyOtherService= inject.get(AnyOtherService);
  }
}


@Component()
  export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent {

  constructor(
    inject: Injector,
    private firstService: FirstService,
    private secondService: SecondService       
  ) {
    super(
     inject,
     firstService
    );       
  }
}
```

The idea is to inject **Injector** and some providers in child component and pass it to parent base component without passing all base class dependencies. 
With passing injector, child classes(components) doesn't need to inject all dependencies of parent(base) class and pass throw super(dep1, dep2..., **baseDep1...**).

> Could you please explain in your answer, why it has to be like you've
>   said with private inside child and protected inside parent?

I think the **injector** shouldn't be the property of child/base class. If will be, the error throws as you comment below. The error is about,  **Base** and **Child** class can't have the same property in their class. That's why we need to omit private/protected or any **access modifier** to **injector** in constructor, also because **Injector** is only needed in constructor to manually inject what we need in some specific cases as this.

Comment: It looks like there is missing something in the abstract class. this.anyOtherService` is not set yet, when you want to push something into it inside the constructor.

Comment: yes, you should define  entityService as BaseComponent property

Comment: This is not fully the desired behaviour. `FirstService` should be injected as `entityService` and `anyOtherService` should only be an instance of `anyOtherService`.

Comment: Also I've got that error message: `Types have separate declarations of a private property 'inject'.`

Comment: removed **private** in child component and set as **protected** on base

Comment: Could you please explain in your answer, why it has to be like you've said with private inside child and protected inside parent? Then I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: can someone confirm that this is not a bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this , make use of injector , export it from appmodule and use it in you base class

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

//exporting injector 
export let AppInjector: Injector;

export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    AppInjector = this.injector;
  }
}
```

and then base.component.ts

```
export abstract class BaseComponent {
  private anyOtherService : AnyOtherService ;
  constructor(
    protected entityService: EntityService,
    // protected anyOtherService: AnyOtherService // @todo add this
  ) {
    this.anyOtherService = AppInjector.get(AnyOtherService );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "export it from appmodule"? Should I add this to my `app.module.ts`?

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski - it like `export let AppInjector: Injector; ` its can be your base module also where your base component resides , its not necessary to be at appmodule level , you can create in you module related to basecomponent and use

Comment: Careful: On the client side this works, but using a "global injector" approach like this with server-side-rendering (SSR) can cause serious problems like seemingly random mismatched user session/cookie data, because Angular sets up a fresh injector for each page load. Assigning `AppInjector` will happen for each request, and since all your requests run in the same runtime, if you pause one request for an async operation and another one comes in and executes, when you continue on the first request you will have the wrong request state within the injector held by `AppInjector`.